# Mockito: How to partially use @InjectMocks-Annotation for MockMvc testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, mockmvc

I need to test an controller and for the most parts it is still enough to use `MockMvc`. But there are still some branches which are very hard to generate an test case for. So I use `Mockito` for stubbing methods and to throw exception for this special test cases.

My controller implements an service and the setup looks like the following:

**MyController.class**:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/myTest")
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = { RequestMethod.POST }, produces = "application/json")
    public final int controllerMethod() {
        return myService.serviceMethod();
    }
}
```

**MyService.class**:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public int serviceMethod() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

So I have multiple test methods and in some methods I mock the `MyService.class` to throw an exception for example.
But in other methods I want to test the normal functionalities. So here occures the problem.
If the tests are not running in the right order, the normal functionality test won't work, because `MyService.class` is still mocked, I guess.
So in this example, the serviceMethod returns null instead of 5.

Is there a way to partially InjectMocks - so I mean only for special methods and not for the class?

Here is the example code:

**MyControllerTest.class**:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Config.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MyControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    @InjectMocks
    @Resource
    MyController myController;

    @Resource
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws SQLException {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).apply(springSecurity()).build();
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "validUser", roles = { "ADMIN" })
    public void testMyController() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(post("/myTest/").with(csrf())).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful()).andExpect(jsonPath("$", is(5)));
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "validUser", roles = { "ADMIN" })
    public void testMyControllerException() throws Exception {
        myService = Mockito.spy(MyService.class);

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        Mockito.doThrow(new IndexOutOfBoundsException()).when(myService).serviceMethod();

        mockMvc.perform(post("/myTest/").with(csrf())).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().is4xxClientError());

        Mockito.verify(myService, Mockito.times(1)).serviceMethod();
    }
}
```

So if I run especially only one of these tests, both working well. 
But if I run both together and `testMyControllerException()` will be executed first, the `testMyController()` fails because of the mocked myService-Instance, I guess.

**Is there any way to fix this problem or must I split this tests into two different testclasses?**

I tried to find a way for unmocking the `myController.class` over the `@After`-Annotation with `Mockito.reset(myController);`. But did't worked for me.

Comment: can you try to move ` MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` to `@Before` block?

Comment: I also tried this. Doesn't work. Because `@Before` will mock the instance for all test methods. For that reason I wrote `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` only into the test methods which needs to be mocked. I think the problems belongs to `MyController.class`. It will be injected for all tests via `@InjectMocks`. But there is no way to partially inject mocks as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be independent of the execution order and without strictly enforce an order, best way is to use the Class-Annotation `@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)`. For each test it generates an newApplicationContext.

Answer (score 0):

For jUnit4 you can use `@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)` https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Test-execution-order

I'd personally prefer to have it in different classes anyway.

Comment: Yes, I also tried this. But I think its not the right way to force an test order. Test should be working independent of the execution order. So there is no workaround ?

Comment: Tests should be also independent and in your case they aren't. This is the workaround if you want to have it in one class. The thing is you are mixing integration test with a unit test of controller in one class and this is what makes issues to you. As I said, personally I'd split this tests in different classes as they are different in terms of level of abstraction.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. So I ended up splitting it into different classes.

Comment: After some tests I noticed, that also the different test classes doesn't solved the problem. Then it depends in which order the test classes will be executed. If the MockitoTestClass will start first, the normal TestClass  instances are still mocked by the MockitoTestClass. So there was still no clean up of the ApplicationContext. I fixed it with `@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)`. It generates for each test an new ApplicationContext.

Comment: @CruelMaze you should rather write your own answer there as it seems that mine is incomplete. Good to know, I haven't ever run into such issue.